# Javascript form validation: the same message is called for every field, maybe some stupid typho?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am practicing Javascript by creating this form validation. I just want a to have each textfield have an different error message. Could anybody explain me what i do wrong? I get no errors
This is my code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function ReloadTextDiv() { 
            var NewText = document.getElementById("naam").value; 
            NewText = NewText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); 
            var DivElement = document.getElementById("textDisplay"); 
            DivElement.innerHTML = NewText; 
        }
        function ReloadTextDiv2() { 
            var NewText = document.getElementById("email").value; 
            NewText = NewText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); 
            var DivElement = document.getElementById("textDisplay2"); 
            DivElement.innerHTML = NewText; 
        } 
        function ReloadTextDiv3() { 
            var NewText = document.getElementById("address").value; 
            NewText = NewText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'); 
            var DivElement = document.getElementById("textDisplay3"); 
            DivElement.innerHTML = NewText; 
        }       
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function formValidator(){

        var naam = document.getElementById('naam');
        var address = document.getElementById('address');
        var email = document.getElementById('email');



        if(isname(naam, "Please enter only letters for your name")){
            if(isAlphanumeric(address, "Numbers and Letters Only for Address")){
                            if(emailValidator(email, "Please enter a valid email address")){
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }



        return false;

    }

    function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
        if(elem.value.length == 0){
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function isname(elem, helperMsg){
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(numericExpression)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function isaddress(elem, helperMsg){
        var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
        if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }



    function emailValidator(elem, helperMsg){
        var emailExp = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;
        if(elem.value.match(emailExp)){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert(helperMsg);
            elem.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="contact_form">  
    <form onsubmit='return formValidator()' >
      <fieldset> 
      <legend>Subscription info</legend>
        <label for="name">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" class="text" onKeyUp="ReloadTextDiv();" />
        <br />
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text" onKeyUp="ReloadTextDiv2();"  />
        <br />
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address"  size="40" class="text" onKeyUp="ReloadTextDiv3();" />
        <legend><input type="submit" value="submit"></legend>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div> 


    <p><span id="textDisplay"></span></p> 
    <p><span id="textDisplay2"></span></p> 
    <p><span id="textDisplay3"></span></p>  
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: Which message are you getting every time?

Comment: Code repetition is your enemy.

Comment: Please don't set *text* content with `innerHTML`

Comment: Please enter only letters for your name

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think trying to validate the name as numeric is not the most reasonable thing to do ;).

```
function isname(elem, helperMsg){
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/; // -> /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
    // ...
}
```

Comment: var nameExpression = /^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]+$/; Like that? Gives me same result

Comment: No, the regular expression for only accepting non-empty strings with nothing more than letters is: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ . Here's a fiddle and the expression is the only thing changed: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra3Wa/